# Injecting JSON data into javascript using PHP - getting confused

Tags: php

I have a neat little JavaScript application that lets users build forms in a drag and drop interface. The form structure is recorded in a JSON format, so after a user clicks save, data such as the following is sent to the server for storage.

```
[{"type":"header","subtype":"h1","label":"This is an example header"},{"type":"radio-group","required":false,"label":"Radio Group","inline":false,"name":"radio-group-1584345334050","other":false,"values":[{"label":"Option 1","value":"option-1"},{"label":"Option 2","value":"option-2"},{"label":"Option 3","value":"option-3"}]},{"type":"text","required":false,"label":"Example Text Field","className":"form-control","name":"text-1584347389110","subtype":"text"}]
```

If a user wants to continue editing their form, I can in theory inject the above data back into the javascript application, and it will rebuild their form. In the JavaScript this is accomplished by the following:

```
dataType: 'json',
formData: 'JSON DATA GOES HERE'
```

The problem I have is that my understanding of PHP is somewhat limited.

I can easily store the JSON data in a database and retrieve it based on the user, but in terms of injecting it back into JavaScript I'm getting a little stuck.

The issue is that when you echo output in PHP, apostrophes and double quotes can easily break the statement. In the above JSON data, the following would work:

```
<?php $formdata = 'DATA FROM DB'; ?>
dataType: 'json',
formData: '<?php echo $formdata; ?>'
```

But, if a user has entered any apostrophes or quote marks in the submitted data, it will obviously break. So how do you go about echoing VARCHAR data that contains a mixture of characters?

Comment: Are datas stored as JSON ?

Comment: At the moment I'm just dumping it into a MySQL text. I could change that to JSON if it makes it easier. I thought for the purpose of basic string storage, text would be easier

Answer (score 0):

Look into json_encode() and json_decode() php function.

`<script type="text/javascript">
var ar = <?php echo json_encode($ar) ?>;
</script>`

follow below link for examples

-> https://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/array.php